# Return resolved Data from Pipe Angular 4 using Behavior Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-routing, angular-services

My service is: **DetailService.ts**

**Send Detail()**

```
sendDetail(id: number) {
    console.log("Snd trandetail");

    const url = this.rootUrl + 'api/Details/Select?ID=' + id;

    this.http.get(url).pipe(
      retry (3)
    ).toPromise()
    .then((data: any) => {
        this.detailSubject.next(data.Entity);
    });
}
```

**GetDetail()**

```
getDetail() {
    console.log("Get trandetail");
    console.log(this.detailSubject);
    return this.detailSubject;
}
```

My resolver is:

**Resolver.ts**

```
resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.DetailService.getDetail()
        .pipe(
            map(object => 
            {
                console.log(object); //Data is fetched  here and printed
                return object;           
            })
        );
}
```

**Route to Child Component:**

```
{
  path: 'edit/:state',
  component: DetailComponent,
  data: {
    text: 'edit',
    nav: true,
    breadcrumbs: true
  },

  resolve: {
    object: Resolver
  },
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]

},

 providers: [ Resolver, DetailService ]
```

**Route to Parent Module:**

```
 {
      path: 'detailsModule',
      loadChildren: 'app/layout/Details/some- 
 details/some-details.module#SomeDetailsModule',
      data: {
          preload: false,
          text: 'trans Amendment'
       },
       canActivate: [AuthGuard]
 },
```

**Problem:**
My route does not seem to navigate to the component. If I enable tracing, I find that **ResolveEnd** is not triggered. 
This is how I am calling the service at component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log("Object from Route");
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.data['object']);   
  this.object = this.route.snapshot.data['object'];
}
```

Where am I  going wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where is the `subscribe()`? And what do you actually want to do?

Comment: @j4rey I am using `Pipe()` and `Map()` to  fetch data and trying to resolve data at navigation.

Comment: Can you explain your logic you are trying to implement here? What I see is your resolver hooked to the `detailSubject` and `sendDetail()` emitting a value. The thing is resolver runs when the route is hit and before the component is created. So the fact that even if you emit a value doesn't do anything. Are you trying to load the same component with the updated data or are you trying to open a new component with the `object` data?

Comment: can you build an example in stackblitz? it will be easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The reason why ResolveEnd was not being triggered was because I missed `      this.tranDetailSubject.complete(); in **Send Detail()** right after next().

**SendDetail():**

```
sendDetail(id: number) {
console.log("Snd trandetail");

const url = this.rootUrl + 'api/Details/Select?ID=' + id;

this.http.get(url).pipe(
  retry (3)
).toPromise()
.then((data: any) => {
    this.detailSubject.next(data.Entity);
    this.detailSubject.complete(); //Tells compiler to trigger ResolveEnd because observable is complete now.

});
}
```

`